# codeigniter advanced mysql sum query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

i have a mysql table with the below data,

```
Table name: test

purchaseno    spent totbdj
1             100   500
1             100   500
2             200   1000
2             300   1000
```

Kindly help with a codeigniter mysql query to achieve the below output

```
purchaseno   spent  totbdj
1            200    500
2            500    1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `SUM` function and the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT purchaseno,
       SUM(spent) AS spent,
       totbdj
FROM test
GROUP BY purchaseno, totbdj
```